# IIS - Running Codeigniter does not execute PHP scripts

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost

I just installed a Codeigniter application on Windows 7 IIS in my local computer.

The routes are ok and the controllers seem to be loading the views, but the PHP scripts on them do not show the passed variables and are interpreted as HTML.

PHP scripts run ok without Codeigniter.

Any clues?

Comment: can you post an example PHP script that is not running? CI handles URL queries differently unless told so and your code may not be accessing the request vars correctly.

Comment: @cryptic any script.. for example: <? echo $variable; ?> where $variable is passed from the controller to the view.

Comment: ah ok so you're saying the values passed the 2nd argument for $this->load->view() are not accessible? If so can you post me the code of how you are passing the value?

Comment: Nope... the values are passed OK. I thik I got it! The PHP version that comes with ISS requires the <?php sentence to be declared, <? won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP version that comes with ISS requires the PHP sentence to be declared.

```
<?php
```

The new opening by itself won't work.

```
<?
```